# Reset select element after replacing the contents of an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I try to create a functionality where I have two (or more) different arrays of elements, like:

```
var cities1 = ["Paris", "London", "Warsaw", "Moscow"];
var cities2 = ["Rome", "Paris", "Berlin", "Amsterdam"];
```

and I can assign them to observableArray which is bound to select element. The problem is when I have one common element in these arrays, like in this example: 'Paris'. When I select 'Paris' and then switch data in observableArray from cities1 to cities2, I don't get the information that selection was changed.

Please check the fiddle I prepared to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zbkkzdsp/3upSH/
Do you know how to do that switching data in observableArray caused 'resetting' selection in select element?

Comment: The answer is that the city hasn't changed. Why would you want to get notified when it hasn't changed?

Comment: This is true, but I would like select element to reload the list and select the first element from the new list and also report change of the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Best points out, city hasn't actually changed. If your cities were viewmodels themselves, then what you describe would happen automatically.

However, since you just have primitives, you'll need to explicitly tell you viewmodel to 'clear' the current value of city when the array changes. It will then automatically select the first element.

You can do this either by setting `self.City` to `''` in your click event, or by subscribing to `self.City.Available` and setting `self.City` to `''` then. You'll also want to make sure you update your subscription to `self.City` to not alert when the updated value is `''`.

In addition, i moved some repeated functionality in your `click` events to a third function and made the two `click` functions proxy this. Your `click` functions were doing the exact same thing, only with different data sets, so this eliminates some code duplication. ATM it seems frivolous because it was only 1 line to start, but if you add more functionality to the City update, this will help you cut down on bugs and make changes more rapidly.

I provided both methods of clearing the City value in the following code sample, and commented out the non-subscribe version so it's there for reference.

```
var cities1 = ["Paris", "London", "Warsaw", "Moscow"];
var cities2 = ["Rome", "Paris", "Berlin", "Amsterdam"];

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.City = ko.observable();
    self.City.Available = ko.observableArray();

    self.City.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if(newValue != '') {
          alert('City has changed to ' + newValue);
        }
    });

    self.City.Available.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       self.City(''); 
    });

    self.click1 = function () {
        self.loadCityList(cities1);
    };

    self.click2 = function () {
        self.loadCityList(cities2);
    };

    self.loadCityList = function(cityList) {
        // clear city w/o subscription
        //self.City('');
        self.City.Available(cityList);        
    }


};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

As a parting note, if you wanted to allow empty strings for city names, or just want a more robust approach to supressing the change alert when the city is cleared, you could add a sub-observable to City and toggle it between true and false. If you did this, i would advise adding a "clearCity" function to encapsulate all of this logic. EX

```
function MyViewModel() {
    ...
    self.City.isLoading = ko.observable(false);

    self.City.subscribe(function (newValue)) {
        if(self.City.isLoading()) {
            self.City.isLoading(false);
        } else {
            alert('City has changed!');
        }
    });

    ...

    //could also put this on city as self.City.clearCity
    self.clearCity = function() {
        self.City.isLoading(true);
        self.City('');
    }

    ...

}
```